# Create a fixed header for an internal container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a fixed header bar,
but the problem is that the header is not a full width navbar like always.

It is a header of the middle container, I have sidebar and container.

So the sidebar should be have the same,
but the container header should stay at the top when I scroll the container.

just like in this code example:

https://plnkr.co/edit/RxSkde8M5wkNg5XoFNEF?p=preview

The pink header "HEADER HERE" should stay at the top always.

code from example:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="side">
    side content
  </div>
  <div class="content">

    <div class="header">
      HEADER HERE
    </div>

    <div class="inner">
      dontcare long content
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fixed it for you: https://plnkr.co/edit/CO910df64twLhEvuaWvb?p=preview;

> Explanation

You set the header in position fixed (fixed to the screen). So a part of your content will be under the header. So here I put a padding-top on the content (you can replace it with a margin). The value of the padding-top has to be the same as the height of the header.

```
.content {
  background: blue;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.content .header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: quick question, how is the header not catching 100% width of the page as it is fixed?   it takes only the content full width....?

Comment: He take full width of the parent: the parent isn't fullwidth. If you want it to take full width of the page you need to put it directly in the body or in an element that is fullwidth.

Answer (score 0):

use this style in your **header div**

```
    <div style="position: fixed; width: 100%" class="header">
      HEADER HERE
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.content .header {background: pink;top:0;position:fixed;width:100%;}

Adding the following to the .content .header makes the header stay at the top always

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position: fixed` to your `.header` class

```
.content .header {
  background: pink;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```