# Making a fixed header for a division

Tags: html, css, scroll, header

I have a webpage that can be scrolled, and a division that can also be scrolled. So I want to have a fixed header for that division, so that it stays in top even after scrolling. However, after [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509952/create-a-fixed-header-for-an-internal-container) example, the header stays on top after scrolling the div, but comes down after scrolling the webpage (comes down meaning relative to the top of the div, relative to the window it stays in the same place). So basically, it needs to go up when the user scrolls down. Here is my code:

```css
#leftDiv,
#centreDiv,
#rightDiv {
  background-color: rgb(14, 89, 133);
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 30vw;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.textWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}

.textWrapper #header1,
.textWrapper #header2 {
  color: red;
  padding-top: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 8;
}

#messages1,
#messages2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 19vw;
}

.backToGroup {
  float: left;
}

.send {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="centreDiv" class="chatpart">
  <span id="insideGroup1">
        <div class="textWrapper">
            <div id="header1">
              Hello world
            </div>
          <span id="messages1">
            khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>khucasjdeugb<br>
          </span>
</div>
<input type="text" id="message1" placeholder="Enter your message here...">
<button class="send" onclick="initializeMessage1()">Send</button>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This simplest way I can think of to solve this is to move the header outside the container, apply `margin-bottom: -30px` to the header, and a `padding-top:30px` to the container or child-element of the container. The value of `30px` could change to whatever you like.

Comment: @admcfajn But how will that stop the header from moving down relative to the division when the page is scrolled?

Comment: Do you mean when the page is scrolled or when the content of the scrollable section beneath the header is scrolled?

Comment: The technique I explained only positions the header at the top of the scrollable section below it.

Comment: To make the whole thing (header and scroll-text with blue background) not scroll with the window, `position:fixed` on a wrapper would be your best bet.